How may I correct a typo?
In this post I tried to add a missing apostrophe in the quotation. However the system refused to store the edit, saying 
Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

(I say "store", not "accept" since I should not have enough reputation to have my edit automatically approved). But this is the only modification I have to do! What's the best thing to do in such cases?

Corretto, grazie.

mau, I think the best thing to do in such cases is to add &nbsp; at the very end of a paragraph at your choice, so that you have in any case the minimal number of 6 characters as the system requests.
Try it, and you will see it works!
